Limiting Date Range in Flutter iOS Date Picker UI?
I want to limit the dates iOS date picker shows, so it should only display three dates: yesterday, today, and tomorrow. I tried setting a minimum and maximum date range, but it still shows past and future dates in the date picker UI.


Try below code, refer CupertinoDatePicker, maximumDate and minimumDate, you need to add intialDate, maximum and minimum date  for your requirement.
CupertinoButton(
            onPressed: () => _showDialog(
              CupertinoDatePicker(
                minimumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
                maximumDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),
                initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
                use24hFormat: false,
                onDateTimeChanged: (DateTime newDateTime) {
                  setState(() => dateTime = newDateTime);
                },
              ),
            ),
            child: Text(
              '${dateTime.month}-${dateTime.day}-${dateTime.year} ${dateTime.hour}:${dateTime.minute}',
              style: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 22.0,
              ),
            ),
          ),

Result-> 

I tried using both the minimum and maximum dates, it shouldn't show any information apart from May 13, today, and May 15 dates in UI.

You want show only 3 dates? Yesterday, Today and Tomorrow am correct? So I have used minimum and maximum date

For CupertinoDatePicker, you need to pass
initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
minimumDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
maximumDate:DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),

For showDatePicker, you need to pass
initialDateTime: DateTime.now(),
firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),

Here is  showDatePicker example:
await showDatePicker(
   context: context,
   initialDate: DateTime.now(),
   firstDate:DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 1)),
   lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 1)),
   initialEntryMode: DatePickerEntryMode.calendarOnly,
   builder: (context, child) {
         return Theme(
               data: ThemeData(
                  primaryColor: Colors.blue,
                  colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch()
                                    .copyWith(secondary: Colors.blue)),
                   child: child!,
          );
   }
);


In CupertinoDatePicker there are two parameters available you just need to pass date in right way
minimumDate : DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days:1)),
so it will calculate the day before todays date
maximumDate : DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days:1)),
it will add the day in current date
full code is like below
   showCupertinoModalPopup(
       context: context,
       builder: (_) => Container(
             height: 190,
             color: const Color.fromARGB(
                 255, 255, 255, 255),
             child: Column(
               children: [
                 SizedBox(
                   height: 180,
                   child:
                       CupertinoDatePicker(
                           minimumDate: DateTime
                                   .now()
                               .subtract(
                                   const Duration(
                                       days:
                                           1)),
                           maximumDate: DateTime
                                   .now()
                               .add(const Duration(
                                   days: 1)),
                           initialDateTime:
                               DateTime
                                   .now(),
                           onDateTimeChanged:
                               (val) {
                             setState(() {});
                           }),
                 ),
               ],
             ),
           ));



I tried using both the minimum and maximum dates, it shouldn't show any information apart from May 13, today, and May 15 dates in UI.
